# Options in Select box displaying on top of menu

Tags: .net, html, css

I have a *.Net* application that is using the *skmMenu* control to manage the menu dropdowns. Directly below the menu is a ***Select*** box.  If you click on the select box the options pop up and stay displayed until you click off or select one.  While they are displayed, if you mouse over the menu the dropdown displays but gets partially hidden behind the **select boxs'** options.

I have the select box `z-index set` to `-1` and the menu *dropdowns* to `z-index set` to `99`.  I can't figure out what to do to get the menu to display on top of everything.

Appreciate any advice for this.

Comment: Code sample, please! Not much we can do with just English words, unfortunately.

Comment: Posting some of your code would definitely be helpful. And for what it's worth, `z-index` only works on non-statically positioned elements, so make sure they have `position: relative` or `absolute`, etc.

Comment: I would have posted code but due to using the skmMenu server control it puts a ton of javascript and junk into the code that is really long and tough to decipher.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the select menu's CSS attribute to:

```
display: none;
```

when the drop down hovers, and then set it to visible again otherwise.

Comment: I used mouse over events to change when the menu was displayed or the drop down list was.  To get rid of the drop down list pop up I used the .blur() to change focus and minimize the list.